# Counting the number of specific characters in substrings

Tags: r, string, awk

I have a file of 8040 rows with two columns, the second column having strings of variable lengths, ranging from 30000 to 200000 characters (DNA sequence). [Below is a sample of 150 characters]

```
X:100670000-101060000    TTCCCCAAACAGCAACTTTAAGGAGCAGCTTCCTTTATGATCCCTGATTGCCTCCCCTTTGTTCCCATAACAAGTAGTTTAAATTTTCTGTTAAAGTCCAAACCACATATTTACAATACCTCGCACC
```

Depending on the length of each string on the second column, I want to divide each string into segments of 10 (10% of the length of the string), count the number of G's and C's of each segment, and get the percentage of G's and C's.

For example, if the first entry of my second column is 39000 characters long, each segment would be 3900 characters in length, and the code would count the occurrences of G's and C's in each segment, add them, and divide by 39000 in this case, to get the percentage.

I tried writing this in **AWK**, but it isn't working. The output I get is for the complete string, and not segments:

```
awk '{
bp_length[$2]= length($2);
bin_size[$2]= bp_length[$2]*0.1;

for(i=1;i<=bp_length[$2];i+=bin_size[$2]){
print gsub("G", "G")"\t"gsub("C", "C")}

}'
```

I get this as an output:

```
79060 76624
```

Would it be easier to solve this problem in **R**, if the output can be represented in a table with 10 columns, with each column representing the 10 segments of each line?

Comment: Please add some sample Inputs along with your nice explanation of question for our better understanding.

Comment: It is difficult to show a sample input, as I said each line has a second column with a string of length between 30000 to 200000 characters.

Comment: Please give sample(where we could put the logic and which looks like actual but NOT actual) data with sample output, let's say give 10 to 15 character long data? So 10% logic will work for any length doesn't matter, let me know on same.

Comment: Ah okay, yes understood.

Comment: Please add sample Output too for shown Input.

Comment: why do you want to split into segments if you later on add up the number of G's and C's in all the segments (and divide them by the length of the string)? It seems like you could count them directly

Comment: @docendodiscimus it wouldn't serve the biological purpose I'm trying to look at :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
# string of length 39000
test <- paste(rep(LETTERS, 1500), collapse = "")

# divide string into 10 equal parts
test2 <- sapply(seq(1, nchar(test), nchar(test)/10), function(x) substr(test, x, x + nchar(test)/10 - 1))

# use str_count from stringr-package to count characters and calculate percentage
library(stringr)
(str_count(test2, "G") + str_count(test2, "C")) / nchar(test) * 100
```

---

Edit for new request:

`if` is not vectorized, therefore you cannot use it to work over the vector `bins` (`test2` in my example).

Instead, use `sapply` in combination with `ifelse`. This way, it'll loop over the ten parts, and output either the calculation in case of `str_count("N") < 10 percent` or `NA` otherwise. Code:

```
X <- sapply(test2, function(x) ifelse(str_count(x, c("N")) < .1*nchar(x), 
                                 (str_count(x, "G") + str_count(x, "C")) / nchar(x) * 100, NA))
names(X) <- seq_along(X)

> X
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308 7.692308
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated your code to this, to get what I wanted! :

(str_count(test2, c("G"))/nchar(test) + str_count(test2, c("C"))/nchar(test))*100

Comment: Great! I've edited the change into my answer for future readers.

Comment: I wanted to update this task and do something different, but I couldn't exactly do it so I'm writing to you again. I want to count the % of G's and C's like before, only if the count of another character "N", is less than 10% of the total bin size. I added an if condition like this: 

if(str_count(bins, c("N")) < 0.1*nchar(bins)){  
  output <- (str_count(bins, c("G"))/nchar(bins) + str_count(bins, c("C"))/nchar(bins))*100
}

It gave me 50 warnings, plus an identical matrix to the original one as an output, but I think the number of lines in this should be less. Can you help me out?

Comment: I have another update on this task. I have the following code from your example: 
`bins <- sapply(seq(1, nchar(data), nchar(data)/10), function(x) substr(data, x, x + nchar(data)/10 - 1))`. Instead of `nchar(data)/10`, I want the substring segments (10) to vary from a list I have. So for my data frame, the first row should be divided into 22 bins, and the code would have `nchar(data)/22`. The second row should be divided into 21 bins, and the code would have `nchar(data)/21`, and so on. How can I do so?

Comment: You could loop through the list with `lapply()` and use `length(x)` for the divisor.

Comment: would it be possible if you could please show it how?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have much time for SO at the moment. Consider opening a new question!

Answer (score 4):

Since you tried to do this exercise in `awk`, I'll give you a `awk` program

This example, shows that the splitting and counting is done correctly :

```
awk '{l=length($2); binsize=int(l/10) + (l%10!=0)
       for(i=1;i<=l;i+=binsize) {
          str=substr($2,i,binsize)
          print str, gsub("G","",str), gsub("C","",str)
       }
     }' <file>
```

giving us the output

```
TTCCCCAAACAGC 1 6
AACTTTAAGGAGC 3 2
AGCTTCCTTTATG 2 3
ATCCCTGATTGCC 2 5
TCCCCTTTGTTCC 1 6
CATAACAAGTAGT 2 2
TTAAATTTTCTGT 1 1
TAAAGTCCAAACC 1 4
ACATATTTACAAT 0 2
ACCTCGCACC 1 6
```

So, in order to get the percentages :

```
awk '{ l=length($2); binsize=int(l/10) + (l%10!=0)
       printf "%-24s (length: %7d, binsize: %7d, lastbin: %7d)\n",$1,l,binsize,l%binsize
       j=1;
       for(i=1;i<=l;i+=binsize) {
         str=substr($2,i,binsize)
         printf "segment %0.3d : %6.3f (%%G) %6.3f (%%C)\n", j++,100*gsub("G","",str)/l, 100*gsub("C","",str)/l
       }
     }' <file>
```

and the output is:

```
X:100670000-101060000    (length:     127, binsize:      13, lastbin:      10)
segment 001 :  0.787 (%G)  4.724 (%C)
segment 002 :  2.362 (%G)  1.575 (%C)
segment 003 :  1.575 (%G)  2.362 (%C)
segment 004 :  1.575 (%G)  3.937 (%C)
segment 005 :  0.787 (%G)  4.724 (%C)
segment 006 :  1.575 (%G)  1.575 (%C)
segment 007 :  0.787 (%G)  0.787 (%C)
segment 008 :  0.787 (%G)  3.150 (%C)
segment 009 :  0.000 (%G)  1.575 (%C)
segment 010 :  0.787 (%G)  4.724 (%C)
```

Comment: Is awk so intelligent to consider this   `(l%10!=0)` as an if condition  ? or it is some sort  of evaluation operator in awk

Comment: @Vicky awk does not return true or false for conditions expressions but a 1 or 0. The statement between brackets is a conditional expression asking if the modulo 10 of `l` is not zero. If it is not zero we need to increase the binsize with 1, and this is just the return value of this conditional expression. This statement assures us that we have maximum 10 bins.

Comment: @Vicky, so if you want a step function of size 5 you could just write `y = 5*(0<x)`